# How to resolve converting system local time to UTC?

Tags: mysql, winforms, visual-studio

I am storing the data details in the database including the date and time of storing the data.

The date and time stored in the database shows `2017-08-01 15:40:38.153` but the same data get displayed in the winforms has the different time i.e. `2017-08-01 8:40 PM`. Rest of the data matches to the data from the database and displayed in exact manner.

I'm sending request to the server, and storing input value like this:

`request.date_from = dateTimePickerFromDate.Value.Date;
 request.date_to = dateTimePickerToDate.Value.Date;`

And my query in the database is

`SELECT * from TableName where (CONVERT(date, Transaction_Date) >= @date_from  and (CONVERT(date,Transaction_Date) <= @date_to))
 order by Transaction_Date desc`

Comment: Probably time zone difference. Maybe it's stored as GMT and displayed in your local time zone.

Comment: My guess is that locally the database time is being converted into your time zone.  Usually time is stored in the database in the GMT time zone.

Comment: Bjorn and Tim, How to fix this issue?